# how to make a p:inputNumber let me enter text by keyboard?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
                                        <div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-6 xl:col-4">
                                            <div class="field">
                                                <span class="ui-float-label label-button">
                                                    <p:inputNumber id="porcentajesolarAgr" required="true" 
                                                        requiredMessage="#{msg['subpropiedad_debe_ingresar_porcentaje_aval']}"
                                                        symbolPosition="s" decimalSeparator="." thousandSeparator="" 
                                                        value="#{subPropiedadBean.subpropiedad.porcentajeSolarStp}" 
                                                        style="text-align: right; direction: rtl;" 
                                                        mode="decimal" />
                                                    <p:outputLabel for="porcentajesolarAgr">#{msg['subpropiedad_procentaje_aval']}</p:outputLabel>
                                                    <p:message for="porcentajesolarAgr"/>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

I need your help and I tried to adapt it so that it accepts decimal numbers, it works but it doesn't let me write, that is, I want to enter information by keyboard but it won't let me just increase with the mouse

```
                                        <div class="col-12 md:col-6 lg:col-6 xl:col-4">
                                            <div class="field">
                                                <span class="ui-float-label label-button">
                                                    <h:inputText id="porcentajeAgr" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['propiedades_debe_ingresar_aval_sib']}"
                                                    value="#{subPropiedadBean.subpropiedad.porcentajeAvalaSibStp}"
                                                    converterMessage="#{msg['propiedades_formato_invalido']}"
                                                    style="text-align: right; direction: rtl;">
                                                    <f:convertNumber type="number" pattern="#,##0.00" />
                                                  </h:inputText>
                                                  <h:outputLabel for="porcentajeAgr">#{msg['subpropiedad_procentaje_aval']}</h:outputLabel>
                                                  <h:message for="porcentajeAgr" />
                                                </span>
                                            </div>                                            
                                        </div>
```

I tried this way but it lets me enter data only that it starts from the decimal point and not at the beginning of the decimal point

Comment: Primefaces version?

Comment: Does it work without `direction: rtl`? And with view locale `en-US`?